# How can I extract vertical text elements of a PDF with PDFMiner.six?

Tags: python, pdf, text-mining, text-extraction, pdfminer

I am trying to extract vertical text elements of a PDF with PDFMiner.six. For this I use the parameters `detect_vertical=True, all_texts=True`. The vertical elements are detected, but unfortunately the spaces between the words are missing. An extracted vertical text element is shown like this:

**Itisalongestablishedfactthatareaderwillbedistractedbythereadablecontentofapagewhenlookingatits layout.**

I have tried two solutions that also address extraction of vertical text elements with PDFMiner.six, but none of them worked me.

Code from second solution:

```
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams(detect_vertical=True, all_texts=True)
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)
```

[Detecting vertical text elements (not just text content) with pdfminer.six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117498/detecting-vertical-text-elements-not-just-text-content-with-pdfminer-six)

[Python PdfMiner - How to get the info on the orientation of each word/sentence included in a pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043955/python-pdfminer-how-to-get-the-info-on-the-orientation-of-each-word-sentence-i)

Is it possible to extract vertical text elements with PDFMiner.six or does it not work with all PDFs? Textract correctly extracts vertical text elements, but for my project I need PDFMinder.six.

Comment: The problem is that a PDF page has several vertical and horizontal text elements. I cannot rotate the text elements individually, I need some form of automation. I extract text from scientific publications, which is a very demanding type of PDF.

Comment: Under the following link you will find a PDF from which I have extracted the text.
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00125-016-3902-y.pdf?pdf=button
Pages 10 and 11 basically consist only of vertical text elements. Pdfminer outputs the text without spaces.